# Cloud Assembly Schema Version Mismatch - Building A Code Pipeline In The CDK

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

After following [the solution on github](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/14738), and the [solution on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66565550/how-to-solve-cdk-cli-version-mismatch), I am still experiencing the same issue when building a code pipeline with AWS CDK.

**Error:**

```
This CDK CLI is not compatible with the CDK library used by your application. Please upgrade the CLI to the latest version.
(Cloud assembly schema version mismatch: Maximum schema version supported is 21.0.0, but found 22.0.0)
```

This error appears in the Code Build Stage of the Code Pipeline. Sourcing the code from Code Commit works successfully, as the first stage.

**CDK Pipeline Code:**

As you can see in the code below, I have the install commands of uninstalling the cdk, and then installing it again. This was the recommended solution provided by the document above. Re-ordering does not influence the outcome.

```
this.codePipeline = new CodePipeline(this, `${environment}-${appName}-`, {
  pipelineName: `${environment}-${appName}-`,
  selfMutation: true,
  crossAccountKeys: false,
  role: this.codePipelineRole,
  synth: new ShellStep("Deployment", {
    input: CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(this.codeRepository, environment, {
      codeBuildCloneOutput: true
    }),
    installCommands: ["npm uninstall -g aws-cdk", "npm i -g npm@latest", "npm install -g aws-cdk"],
    commands: [
      "cd backend",
      "npm ci",
      "npm run build",
      "npx cdk synth",
    ],
    primaryOutputDirectory: "backend/cdk.out",
  })
});
```

**Dependencies in the `package.json` file:**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-appsync-alpha": "^2.55.1-alpha.0",
    "aws-cdk-lib": "^2.58.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1278.0",
    "constructs": "^10.1.204",
    "git-branch": "^2.0.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to do without the `npx` in `npx cdk synth`. I removed it and the code worked. This was also experienced when attempting to run `npx cdk synth` locally.

**Solution:** `cdk synth`

Comment: Works for me! Not sure why they are recommending running `cdk` with `npx`! Seems a fresh install is necessary, using `installCommands` or otherwise.